# How do I get a simple alert on a button click?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I was playing around with a simple app and I want to show an alert when a button is clicked.

The code I have so far is:

```
package max.helloworld.firstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private Button closeButton;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.closeButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.close);
    this.closeButton.setKeyListener(new onClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();               
            alertDialog.setTitle("Transformers");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Optimus Prime");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                }
            });
            //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            alertDialog.show();
            finish();
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

The issue is where it says AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

It says the constructor is undefined. How do I fix that please?

Comment: why do you call finish after that? You have setContentView 2 times - why is that?

Comment: I removed those, I was looking at code for various sites and must have put that in twice.

Answer (score 5):

Change this line:

```
`AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();`
```

To:

```
`AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivityName.this);`
```

Comment: In your revised code, should there still be a `.create()`?

Answer (score 3):

The keyword `this` resolves to the instance of `OnClickListener` at that scope.  To refer back to your activity instance replace `this` with `HelloWorldActivity.this`

Comment: Hi, thanks that got rid of the error. But nothing happens now when I click the button on my view. Any ideas? I also removed `finish();` and `this.setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Comment: instead of setKeyListener - setOnClickListener

Comment: After doing that, the new error is "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new onClickListener(){})"   Nevermind, it works now. Thank you!

Comment: there are two different OnClickListener interfaces.  One is a child of View and the other is of DialogInterface.  Fully qualify it as View.OnClickListener